# Assembly emu 8086 input click specific button 2040

Tags: assembly, dos, emu8086

This is my code:

```
DSEG    SEGMENT 'DATA'

; add DATA

DSEG    ENDS

SSEG    SEGMENT STACK   'STACK'
        DW      100h    DUP(?)
SSEG    ENDS

CSEG    SEGMENT 'CODE'

;*******************************************

START   PROC    FAR

; Store return address to OS:
    PUSH    DS
    MOV     AX, 0
    PUSH    AX

; set segment registers:
    MOV     AX, DSEG
    MOV     DS, AX
    MOV     ES, AX

; initialization
    MOV DX, 2040h
    MOV AL, 00h
    OUT DX, AL
    MOV DX, 2080h
    OUT DX, AL  

NEXT:   
    MOV DX, 2080h ; input data entrada dos buttons
    IN  AX, DX    ; 16-bit input

    MOV DX, 2040h ; output data / saida para ASCII LCD display
    OUT DX, AL

    JMP NEXT ; infinit loop


; return to operating system:
    RET
START   ENDP

;*******************************************

CSEG    ENDS 

        END    START    ; set entry point.
```

I would like to pick an action when button 1 was is pressed, like a call to a another procedure.

Comment: Among other things, what plugin are you using that requires port 0x2080 and 0x2040? (Is it supplied by your school/class). What plugin provides the buttons?

Comment: @MichaelPetch I`m using emulator kit , using the virtual devices inside the emu8086, and really need some  help to figure this out, the event on click the button 1 to call a procedure.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution to my own problem. The code I used is below:

```
DSEG    SEGMENT 'DATA'

msg1:    db      "PLAY!", 0Dh,0Ah, 24h
msg2:    db      "PAUSE!", 0Dh,0Ah, 24h
msg3:    db      "STOP!", 0Dh,0Ah, 24h
msg4:    db      "UP!", 0Dh,0Ah, 24h
msg5:    db      "DOWN!", 0Dh,0Ah, 24h

DSEG    ENDS

SSEG    SEGMENT STACK   'STACK'
        DW      100h    DUP(?)
SSEG    ENDS

CSEG    SEGMENT 'CODE'

;*******************************************

START   PROC    FAR

; Store return address to OS:
    PUSH    DS
    MOV     AX, 0
    PUSH    AX

; set segment registers:
    MOV     AX, DSEG
    MOV     DS, AX
    MOV     ES, AX

; initialization
    MOV DX, 2040h
    MOV AL, 00h
    OUT DX, AL
    MOV DX, 2080h
    OUT DX, AL  

NEXT:   
    MOV DX, 2080h ; input data entrada dos buttons
    IN  AX, DX    ; 16-bit input

    CMP AL,02
    JE  PLAY

    CMP AL,02
    JE  PAUSE

    CMP AL,04
    JE  STOP

    CMP AL,01
    JE  UP

    CMP AH,01
    JE  DOWN


    MOV DX, 2040h ; output data / saida para ASCII LCD display
    OUT DX, AL

    JMP NEXT ; infinit loop


; return to operating system:
    RET
START   ENDP



PLAY PROC

        mov     dx, msg1  ; load offset of msg into dx.
        mov     ah, 09h  ; print function is 9.
        int     21h      ; do it!

        mov     ah, 0 
        int     16h      ; wait for any key....  
    RET          
PLAY ENDP 

PAUSE PROC

        mov     dx, msg2  ; load offset of msg into dx.
        mov     ah, 09h  ; print function is 9.
        int     21h      ; do it!

        mov     ah, 0 
        int     16h      ; wait for any key....  
    RET          
PAUSE ENDP 

STOP PROC

        mov     dx, msg3  ; load offset of msg into dx.
        mov     ah, 09h  ; print function is 9.
        int     21h      ; do it!

        mov     ah, 0 
        int     16h      ; wait for any key....  
    RET          
STOP ENDP

UP PROC

        mov     dx, msg4  ; load offset of msg into dx.
        mov     ah, 09h  ; print function is 9.
        int     21h      ; do it!

        mov     ah, 0 
        int     16h      ; wait for any key....  
    RET          
UP ENDP 

DOWN PROC

        mov     dx, msg5  ; load offset of msg into dx.
        mov     ah, 09h  ; print function is 9.
        int     21h      ; do it!

        mov     ah, 0 
        int     16h      ; wait for any key....  
    RET          
DOWN ENDP 


;*******************************************

CSEG    ENDS 

        END    START    ; set entry point.
```

Comment: Do take the time to format this program. Also please explain why this program answers the question.

Comment: I have to agree with @user3144770 : I won't consider an upvote until there is some general explanation (besides code and code comments) of how this works in general, and how it solves the OPs question (It doesn't have to be overly fancy).

Comment: A discussion on why you chose to restart the program via `RET` from each button handler etc would probably help the OP.

Comment: Why do you have `CMP AL,02` `JE  PLAY` `CMP AL,02` `JE  PAUSE` . That seems to be checking both buttons for the same thing. How does PAUSE get called?

Comment: @MichaelPetch so guys i was trying to identify that if i push button 1 on the keyboard input, virtual device (2080h), that the value of the register AL changes to 01 so i can do a compare with the value and call a proc , that I was asking, but i'm just trying to help; I can delete this post later if result in troubles.